# Conditionnal CSV prompting

Tags: xetex, etoolbox, csvsimple, filecontents

I'm asking for your help for a specific problem I have no clue about.

My goal is to have conditionnal CSV printed in a table (did not include that print part) :

```
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\input{info.tex} 

\csvreader[separator=semicolon]{budget.csv}
{Phase=\phase, Descriptif=\descriptif, NombreJEH=\nbJEH, PrixJEH=\puJEH} 
   
\end{document}
```

If I put in `info.tex` the following statement :

```
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{budget.csv}
Phase   ;   Descriptif;             NombreJEH   ;   PrixJEH 
Phase 1 ;   Nom de la phase ;       2           ;   350         
Phase 2 ;   Nom de la phase ;       3           ;   360             
Phase 3 ;   Rédaction du rapport ;  1           ;   340             
\end{filecontents}
```

it does work perfectly but if I use the following :

```
\ifstrequal{a}{a}
{
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{planningEtBudget.csv}
Phase   ;   Descriptif;             NombreJEH   ;   PrixJEH 
Phase 1 ;   Nom de la phase ;       2           ;   350         
Phase 2 ;   Nom de la phase ;       3           ;   360             
Phase 3 ;   Rédaction du rapport ;  1           ;   340             
\end{filecontents}
}
```

I have the following error returned :

> Package csvsimple Error: File 'planningEtBudget.csv' starts with an empty line!.
> See the csvsimple package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.
> ...
> l.175 \\midrule}
> This error message was generated by an \errmessage
> command, so I can't give any explicit help.
> Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
> and deduce the truth by order and method.

I have no idea why it does behave like this. I'm using XeLaTex compiler with 2022 version of TeX on Overleaf. Hope I have been clear enough for you to help me, please ask if you need any more information.

Thank you !

-Clem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Currently it's quite unclear why you are doing things the way you are doing them. 1. You really don't need to input the TeX file containing the csv. If it is small enough, you can put the `filecontents` environment directly in your working file. If it is too long, then just create a file named `budget.csv` manually and don't generate it with TeX. 2. You have shown an `\ifstrequal` snippet, but what you exactly want to achieve is not very clear. At least the way you have written, there should be a percent sign after the opening brace `{` of the argument to avoid space char.

Comment: The whole thing is that this is supposed to be used by people that just have basics (I mean even more than me) on LaTeX, the budget.csv part is just part of a longer info.tex file that require them to fill infos. The goal is depending on those filled info to only create the corresponding budget file. Can you elaborate on the last part ? I don't get it. Thanks for your comment ! Hope it is clearer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the first point. It is clear now and I get the requirement. About the next part, I really am not able to understand what is the purpose of putting `\ifstrequal{a}{a}{<true-code>}{<false-code>}`. This command tests if the first argument is equal to the second argument. If it is equal it runs the true-code and if it is false it runs the false-code. You have `a` as the first as well as the second argument, which basically means it is equal, so always the true-code is going to get executed. Also false-code is completely absent in your code which also is a bug.

Comment: So without `\ifstrequal{a}{a}` part also your code should work exactly the same way. Also with lesser errors as the false-code isn't required. The way you are inputting the condition, i.e., testing two `a`s, false-code is irrelevant anyways.

Comment: "a" was only used as a test for me, it was meant to be changed to check for the value of a variable. Further testing on local setup shown me that with the \ifstrequal part, the csv is properly generated but is empty so seems really weird to me. Anyway, I figured out out to do what I was looking for in another way (generated all csv with different names and passed the test in the \csvreader part). Thanks for your help ! (Tell me if I should archive this or not ?)

Comment: I am glad that you found a solution. Just as a side remark, it would have been better if you had posted an example which would demonstrate the problem you are facing. Right now, it produces an error. Also it is not complete, e.g., the code lacks a `\documentclass`. I know it's trivial, but for convenience it is always good to add a full example, but it being your first question; your efforts are still commendable. You can delete this question, but as a resource for others facing the problem you could add a solution yourself too. Not an obligation. Just something you can do in your leisure time